Google sheets error message, but formula is identical. Importrange with Query
This is pulling an error:

"Error
Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: NO_COLUMN: Col8"

=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s-ISsxDYTxHaY3CrOL0f_oksWpG-sUY-QLXNJIPtyaM/edit#gid=0", "Total Leads!A2:J") , IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s-ISsxDYTxHaY3CrOL0f_oksWpG-sUY-QLXNJIPtyaM/edit#gid=0", "Total Leads!K2:T")}, "WHERE Col8= 'xxxxxxxx'")]
This one is not.
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQ9xOIc3R0vblk4D07iNnT2SW27DEuoimdqRKlTyBws/edit#gid=0", "Total Leads!A2:J") , IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lQ9xOIc3R0vblk4D07iNnT2SW27DEuoimdqRKlTyBws/edit#gid=0", "Total Leads!K2:T")}, "WHERE Col8= 'xxxxxxx'")
I have tried both a filter import and this formula and this formula returns what I need, but it isn't working in the older sheet.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The importrange() function will error out if it has not been authorized.
To grant the necessary permission to importrange(), you need to unwrap it so that the import gets initiated from outside the query(), like this:
=importrange("1lQ9xOIc3R0vblk4D07iNnT2SW27DEuoimdqRKlTyBws", "A1")

Repeat that with both spreadsheet IDs and verify that the value in cell A1 gets imported correctly.
Another possible issue is that the source spreadsheet does not have quite that many columns. The { array expression } will error out if the spreadsheet only has columns up to column S, for example.
Further, the formulas you quote will only get data from their first import, because the array expression therein combines arrays horizontally. Use vstack() to combine them vertically, like this:
=query( 
 vstack( 
   importrange("1lQ9xOIc3R0vblk4D07iNnT2SW27DEuoimdqRKlTyBws", "Total Leads!A2:J"), 
   importrange("1lQ9xOIc3R0vblk4D07iNnT2SW27DEuoimdqRKlTyBws", "Total Leads!K2:T") 
  ), 
  "where Col8= 'xxxxxxx' ", 
  0 
)

